# EntityManager find() hangs

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager

I'm having a problem where `entityManager.find()` hangs with no error message.  Yet, when I use `entityManager.createQuery()` it successfully returns.  What is different about `.find()` that is causing it to hang?

For example,

```
// this hangs
MyObject mo = entityManager.find(MyObject.class, id);

//this works
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select o from MyObject o where o.id = :id")
query.setParameter("id",id);
MyObject mo = query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question.  Turns out that `MyObject` had a `@NamedEntityGraph` with an invalid `@NamedAttributeNode`.  (I had included a child object as a regular attribute when it should have been a `@NamedSubgraph`). When I deleted the invalid `@NamedAttributeNode`, the `.find()` returned successfully.